# Can I embed a google document in Github's readme.md using markdown?

Tags: github, markdown, readme

I am trying to embed a google docs in Github's readme.md using markdown. Is this possible?

I have done the following:

1. Published the document to web and copied the iframe code.
2. Pasted the code in markdown. Nothing happens.
3. Pasted the code between  and nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible.  When GitHub renders a README or other text document on the site, it gets passed through a filter to sanitize it and remove anything potentially malicious, including JavaScript and iframes.  That's because these documents are rendered in the context of the github.com domain, and any malicious code could steal user credentials or otherwise create privacy or security problems.

Note that even if you could bypass the sanitizer, GitHub sends a `Content-Security-Policy` header that restricts JavaScript to a single, specific domain and rejects all frames, so your browser would not render such content, and it would use the report URI to send a notification to GitHub that a violation had been detected.

You could save the Google Doc as Markdown, AsciiDoc, or HTML and place it in your repository for people to use if you want it to be visible on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Docs to Markdown Pro](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/docs_to_markdown_pro/483386994804) add on to commit Google Docs as a Markdown to GitHub repository.

Set the root directory as Markdown file location and use the file name readme.md while committing.